# Multiple dictionary fields python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way in python to create multiple fields with the same name in a dictionary, which is then going to create a JSON file.

For example:

```
photos_dictionary={ 'ID': '',
                    'URL':'',
                    'TAGS':[''],
                    'LATITUDE':'',
                    'LONGTITUDE':''}
```

The above will create a dictionary with all required fields then I will be using the json library to create a json file.

My question is, one image will have all those values: So ideally I would like

```
photos_dictionary={ 'ID': '',
                    'URL':'',
                    'TAGS':[''],
                    'LATITUDE':'',
                    'LONGTITUDE':''}
```

to repeat itself over and over for each image. I understand that I can append to elements in a dictionary, but as I have close to 9000 unique image Ids I dont want to append this to a single element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just create a photos_dictionary for each image, then add it to a list called images?

Comment: I really don't understand what the actual question is.

Comment: Apologies about the confusion, im still trying to get my head around it myself. Maybe this will clear it up:
I want something like this:

ID: ''
URL:''
TAGS:[]
'LATITUDE': ''
'LONGITUDE': ''

To be one image, then repeated over and over. But still within a global list?

Comment: In fairness I think @JosephJames kinda answered it for me...

Comment: You can't have the same key twice in a dictionary. I'm with @JosephJames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

I'd suggest you either create a *list* of dictionaries - one per photo, or a *dict of dicts*, where the unique ID is the key for each of the inner dicts:

Something like:

```
output = []
for id, url, tags, lat, lon in myPhotoData:
   output.append({'ID': id, 'URL': url, ...etc})
# now convert output to JSON... 
# JSON supports lists (arrays) as well as objects (dicts)
```

or:

```
output = {}
for id, url, tags, lat, lon in myPhotoData:
   output[id] = {'ID': id, 'URL': url, ...etc}
# now convert output to JSON...
# ID field is optional in the inner dict since we have it as a key anyway
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I think I'm going to go for the dict of dicts method!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are technical ways to have a dict-like data structure whose keys may occur multiple times, e.g. https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/.

But then, this is not the data structure that you are looking for: with multiple IDs and, e.g., multiple URLs, you'd need some way to store which URL corresponds to which ID. Therefore, the aforementioned list or dict of dicts would be the way to go.

If you start doing things with each of these dicts, a good factoring of your code would be to implement an `Image` class whose methods describe operations on one image and whose instance attributes store the data fields of one image. Then your overall data structure might be a list or dict of `Image` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the idea is to store this dict of dicts as a JSON file. Then use pyLucene or pySolr (undecided) for indexing.